# Displaying HTML Content in Razor WebGrid

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am trying to use a webgrid to display display content in HTML format. How do I go about it?

Screen Shot:

[image]

My Grid:

```
@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" }, fillEmptyRows: false, tableStyle: "table", footerStyle: "foot", mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, firstText: "<< First", previousText: "< Prev", nextText: "Next >", lastText: "Last >>", columns: new[] {
grid.Column("PublishedContent",
                header: "Content"
    ),
            grid.Column("Layout", header: "Layout"),
            grid.Column("_Status", header: "Status"),

    grid.Column("",
                header: "Actions", style: "_action",
                format: @<text>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Published", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "editDialog"/*, data_dialog_id = "edit-Dialog"*/ })
                    |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "_DeletePublished", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "confirmDialog" })
                </text>
    )
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Html.Raw()` in the `format` parameter to prevent HtmlEncoding taking place:

```
grid.Column("PublishedContent", header: "Content", format: @<text>@Html.Raw(item.PublishedContent)</text>)
```